# ASP.NET Core Route match first part with wild card ending

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

I'd like to define a route which only needs to match the first few segements, and ignores the rest:

```
[Route("public/portfolio/{publicPortfolioId}")]
```

The idea is that anything that **starts** with `public/portfolio/myid` would match.  This should result in a match for:

```
public/portfolio/myid
public/portfolio/myid/something
public/portfolio/myid/something/that/doesnt/exist
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a *catch-all* parameter.

```
[Route("public/portfolio/{publicPortfolioId}/{*remainder}")]
```

Here are two ways that you can use it.

Ignore the remainder:

```
[Route("public/portfolio/{publicPortfolioId}/{*remainder}")]
public IActionResult DemoAction(int publicPortfolioId) 
{
    return Json(new 
    { 
        publicPortfolioId 
    });
}
```

Capture the remainder:

```
[Route("public/portfolio/{publicPortfolioId}/{*remainder}")]
public IActionResult DemoAction(int publicPortfolioId, string remainder)
{
    return Json(new
    {
        publicPortfolioId,
        remainder
    });
}
```

See also: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-2.1